# Three table with value join query base value is first ,secound and third table

Tags: mysql

i need to develop the query with join or any thing i can't make it

my concept is the first table have a usr id and usr type id 
the second table have details of usr type and id and usr master details id
the third table have usr master details and id my question is how i select the value of those three table

Sample table is

```
user_details
usr_id   Name  us_ty_id
25       john     2
34       sam      3
24       rose     1

user_type
us_ty_id    type    usr_ma_id
1            dev      2
2            desi     1
3            test     2

user_master
usr_ma_id   details
1            team1
2            team2
3            team3
```

my output like below

```
usr_id   type     details
34       test      team3
```

the first table us_type_id find the type and usr_ma_id in second and find the details of selected id of usr_ma_id in second table and find the details

ple help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_details d
INNER JOIN user_type t ON t.us_ty_id = d.us_ty_id
INNER JOIN user_master m ON m.usr_ma_id = t.usr_ma_id;
```

Comment: thank u lot and i was add one condition in the end SELECT *
FROM user_details d
INNER JOIN user_type t ON t.us_ty_id = d.us_ty_id
INNER JOIN user_master m ON m.usr_ma_id = t.usr_ma_id where d.usr_id=$_SESSION['id'];